# Compare 2 txt files on talend, and display the differences

Tags: java, unix, talend

I would like to compare 2 txt files on talend, and display the differences.

For this I thought about "tfileCompare" but I don’t know how to display the differences.
I could also use a shell or a unix command "diff" but how do I integrate this on talend?

Do you have any ideas for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a tMap component.

1. Create a new Job in Talend.
2. Use two tfileinputdelimited components to read your text files.
3. Use a tmap to join the two tfileinputdelimited components and then perform a join to get the differences.

[image]

4. In the tmap settings, use a inner join between the two source files then set the "catch lookup inner join rejects" to true in your output:

[image]

Refer this link for more details: https://help.talend.com/r/mjoDghHoMPI0yuyZ83a13Q/5hp9Au3KXs6Dn73ji9uJmA